# Torquebox services: niceness?

Tags: torquebox, nice

I'm considering moving over to Torquebox, but I need to set the nice level of one of the external daemons i want to change to a Service to 19. Is there any equivalent way of doing this in Torquebox, so that a service has lower run time priority than anything else, especially the 'web' part of Torquebox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Services are just POROs conforming to API TorqueBox can work with. TorqueBox expects you to yield his thread back as soon as possible after calling `Service#start`, which is why services are customarily run within separate worker threads and you can set priority of the worker thread using `Thread#priority` (see https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/DifferencesBetweenMriAndJruby#thread-priority) - which is the `Thread` equivalent of `nice`

Should be as simple as:

```
class Service
  def start
    @worker = Thread.new do
      # do servicy stuff
    end
    @worker.priority = ...
  end

  def stop
    @worker.stop
  end

end
```

However, Java seems to suffer some quirks on this that are OS dependant (see [Setting priority to Java's threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1617963/setting-priority-to-javas-threads) and [Throttling CPU from within Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12302196/throttling-cpu-from-within-java?lq=1)) and JRuby inherits those quirks.

Having those quirks in mind, if all else fails, you can always do sleep 0.01 every now and then to stagger execution a bit and yield CPU time to other jobs, you can do this deterministically (`sleep 0.01 if count%100==0`) or you can do this non-deterministically for pretty much same effect and simpler code (`sleep 0.01 if random(100)==0`) - and play with the exact number (1, 10, 100, 1000, ...),

as far as I can tell EventMachine uses sleep 0.01 in the reactor thread to prevent pegging the CPU, this approach is not as outlandish as it sounds at first.

Comment: looks like linux java doesnt allow you to lower priority on a thread unless you are root.... thats pretty damn ridiculous.

Comment: not sure if this'll work but for anybody else reading this you may want to give it a try: http://tech.stolsvik.com/2010/01/linux-java-thread-priorities-workaround.html