# Is there a way to restrict CPU usage to a percentage during runtime for JVM or Dalvik?

Tags: java, android, jvm

What I am asking is if there is a way, during runtime, to restrict the percentage of CPU accessible by a thread in JVM or in Dalvik? See example:

```
private void functionRunningInsideThread()
{
    // Do something

    // Lower access to CPU cycles

    // Do something else (with access to lower CPU cycles)

    // Remove CPU restrictions

    return;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: no there isn't a way to do it reliably, AFAIK.

Longer answer: there are (at least) two problems here:

1. In a conventional JVM, there is no safe way for one thread to pause the execution of another thread, unless the second thread is cooperating; i.e. it is regularly checking to see if it should pause.
2. It is difficult to monitor the percentage CPU time used by a thread.  In theory, you can get the total CPU usage for a thread using the `ThreadMXBean` API.  However:

   - the quantity may not be available, and
   - even if it is, going from the total CPU usage for a thread to the percentage usage over a given period is not straightforward.

However, if you were willing to be a bit rough-and-ready, you could have a thread periodically check its own CPU usage using `ThreadMXBean.getCurrentThreadCPUTime` and compare to elapsed time measured using `System.getTimeMillis`.  If the thread finds it is using to much CPU, it can simply call `Thread.sleep()`.

See also:

- [Throttling CPU/Memory usage of a Thread in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1202184/throttling-cpu-memory-usage-of-a-thread-in-java)

Comment: I appreciate the detailed answer. Didn't know about Thread profiling, so I learned something there.
The reason I would want to use this is to be able to slow down a threads execution so as to delay it until another thread has finished _without_ needing to use sleep or wait. But I understand that it would be bad code and unreliable. Thanks @Stephen.