# Memory and CPU limits for PhantomJS Page?

Tags: phantomjs

PhantomJS Page executed in sandbox, but there's still a possibility for infinite loop and memory flooding.

Is there a way to set limits for memory and CPU available for the Page?

Comment: Try this :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1202184/throttling-cpu-memory-usage-of-a-thread-in-java