# pthread_attr_t equivalent in C11

Tags: multithreading, c11

I'm porting one Linux application to Windows using Visual Studio 2015. I know there is pthread for Windows project out there but I want to convert all pthread calls to c11 standard thread libraries. However, I found the document extremely difficult to find. To be specific, I'm trying to find the equivalent of pthread_attr_t in C11 thread but could not find any.

Can somebody point out reference materials? Thanks!

Comment: Visual Studio doesn't follow C11 (it barely follows any C standard). You'll need to use a standard compliant C compiler instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no equivalent to attributes for C11 thread creation. The only additional state that a thread can have is to be detached. This you achieve by calling `thrd_detach`.

Comment: Then, is there any standard APIs for set stack size, or priority?

Comment: Thread priorities - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18884510/portable-way-of-setting-stdthread-priority-in-c11