# Python multiprocessing calling a lib can be viewed as multithreading?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I am developing a C++ so lib for Python use. In Python code, the handle of the lib is shared between multi processes (maybe via `multiprocessing`) and called. My question is:

1. From the perspective of my lib, can being called from different processes be viewed as multi threading?
2. If so, what thread is using by Python, is `pthread` or sth? Can I configure it?
3. If not, what is really happening behind it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you asking in order to know if you should use locks in your lib's single-threaded code?

Comment: @Adam.Er8 yes, I am doing sth around thread-safe. I think it's necessary?

Comment: Multiprocessing and multithreading are two different things. Regardless of which is being used, shared resources must be protected via mutexes like locks to prevent concurrent access to them.

Comment: @martinroblem.eau I agree with you on the difference between multi-threading and muti-processing. but it doesn't solve my problem

Comment: Then I guess I don't understand your question (nor does anyone else).

Comment: @martineau Sorry, bro. It's my bad. I am trying my best to make it clear. I know multi-processing and multi-threading are two different things, and I agree with you doing some thread-safe things both under multi-threading and multi-processing. I am wondering if calling my lib under a multiple thread circumstance (C++ test code) is exactly the same as calling from multi-processing Python?

Comment: Further, since `std::thread` can't set the priority, so I am trying to wrap it with some `pthread` api (Maybe like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18884510/portable-way-of-setting-stdthread-priority-in-c11/31652324#31652324) ) Is it possible for Python?