# C++ multithreading high CPU usage problem

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading

I have a simple code like below. This code hits high CPU usage like 70%-80%.

```
#include <thread>

void thread_1()
{
    while (true)
    {
        /*
            Do some stuff
            For example, copy a buffer to another.
        */
    }
}


void thread_2()
{
    while (true)
    {
        /*
            Do some stuff here as well
            For example, asign some values.
        */
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::thread thread_obj_1(thread_1);
    std::thread thread_obj_2(thread_2);

    thread_obj_1.join();
    thread_obj_2.join();

    return 0;
}
```

But if I put some sleep to the threads, it does not. Why is this happening? And how can I solve this high CPU usage without using sleep? Is there any better and professional way to let the operating system (in my case Windows) give CPU resources to other processes and keep the usage low in my application?

The code with sleep is below.

```
#include <thread>

void thread_1()
{
    while (true)
    {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(5));

        /*
            Do some stuff
            For example, copy a buffer to another.
        */
    }
}


void thread_2()
{
    while (true)
    {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(5));

        /*
            Do some stuff here as well
            For example, asign some values.
        */
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::thread thread_obj_1(thread_1);
    std::thread thread_obj_2(thread_2);

    thread_obj_1.join();
    thread_obj_2.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `while (true) { }` without `sleep_for()`, when does this yield any time for other threads/processes?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie , If you mean std::this_thread::yield I tried it in the same manner that I show you above. But it did not help. CPU usage was still high as mentioned.

Comment: @Thow no, he means that that's a tight loop, doing your `/*some stuff*/` forever, it's normal that it uses 100% of the (virtual) core it runs on.

Comment: You basically have a busy loop for 1,so that is high CPU load for you. Letting a thread sleep will unschedule it for a while freeing up the CPU to do other things.

Comment: This looks like [XY problem](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). I'm pretty sure whole problem is hidden in part where comment in code is placed. On other hand you can check this possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18884510/1387438

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thread will stay in the run or ready state as long as it's not instructed to sleep or block on I/O.  This translates to higher CPU usage from the various task manager or control panels in your OS.

You're putting the thread to sleep on each iteration of the loop for 5ms. If the actual work required on each iteration of the loop only takes 1ms of processing power, your thread will only use 1/6 of a cpu core.

Most real-world threads:

- Are implicitly blocked from doing anything because it's waiting for a file I/O or network call to complete.  It's not unusual for a thread to wait an entire second for data before being able to do a millisecond of processing on it.
- Have a finite amount of work and eventually finishes and just "waits" using an OS primitive signal (ala conditional variable, semaphore, etc...) from another thread before it can start again. A thread waiting on a threading or kernel primitive is effectively sleeping.
- Or the thread terminates when there is nothing to do.

If you are looking to have your app be more "background" than "foreground" so that it doesn't impact other work the user may want to do consider any of the following:

- Periodic sleep statements as you have them or self-throttling with sleep statements when the code detects an active user or overall high CPU load.
- Run your threads at a lower priority. This is OS specific. For example on Windows, you'd just call `SetThreadPriority(GetCurrentThread(), THREAD_PRIORITY_BELOW_NORMAL)` to run at a lower priority.
- Run with less threads, if that's an option
- Doing a "thread yield" operation or "sleep(0)" to basically allow another waiting thread a chance to run for a quantum.