# How to make sure thread has copied resource before detach?

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

I need create a new thread using `pthread_create`, which will detach later. The new thread will need to copy some content over, which will go out of scope after detached. Below is an example. My question is how to make sure that the content is copied to the new thread before detach?

I have to use pthread here to fine-tune thread priority.

```cpp
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std::chrono_literals;

void new_thread() {
    int val = 65535;
    pthread_t pid;
    pthread_create(&pid, NULL, [](void* ptr)->void *{
        auto val_ptr = static_cast<int*>(ptr);
        auto val = *val_ptr;  // <-- copy from main thread
        std::cout<<"new thread: copied"<<std::endl;
        for (int i = 0; i<10; ++i) {
            std::cout<<"new thread: "<<"i:"<<i<<" val:"<<val<<std::endl;
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(10ms);
        }
        return nullptr;
    }, &val);
    std::cout<<"new thread created"<<std::endl;
    pthread_detach(pid);  // need to make sure val is copied before detach
    std::cout<<"new thread detached"<<std::endl;
}

int main() {
    new_thread();
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
}
```

Comment: Do you know about `pthread_mutex_t` and a `pthread_cond_t`, how they work, and how to use them? Even better: get rid of everything, and use `std::thread`, `std::mutex` and `std::condition_variable`, instead. After all: you're writing C++ instead of C.

Comment: Use a condition variable (`pthread_cond_t`)?

Comment: First of all this is C++ so do not use pthread. Standard threading support has been in since C++11. Also the use of detach is usually not needed at all and will get you into trouble if your thread uses resources from the main program. Also the fact you need to use a `void*` is usually a sign you're not using a library that is really compatible with C++

Comment: To answer your question : you probably need a condition variable (+mutex +bool) to signal that the copying has taken place. And your new thread function should wait after detach until that bool becomes true using condition variable wait.

Comment: Thanks for all comments above. I will check everything you guys mentioned. I need to use `pthread` to do some fine-tuning because this is a real-time application on a real-time os.

Comment: Is there some reason you're not using the modern thread classes?

Comment: Maybe you can still use std::thread. It is possible to get a native handle you can still use in OS specific calls : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18884510/portable-way-of-setting-stdthread-priority-in-c11

Comment: Detaching threads often makes things _harder_ instead of easier. You could use a `std::jthread` to have the thread auto-join when it's destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question here:

I think I put too much emphasis on using `pthread` in the question, while this could still be an issue with `std::thread`.

Based on the suggestions, I tried 3 approaches below: using `pthread`, using `std::thread`, and using `std::thread` + lambda capture, which makes copying data into new thread an non-issue. Any suggestions / corrections are welcome.

```cpp
#include <thread>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>

using namespace std::chrono_literals;

void new_pthread() {
    pthread_t pid;

    struct data_to_new_thread_t{
        int val = 11111;
        pthread_mutex_t mux = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
        pthread_cond_t cv = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
    } data;

    pthread_create(&pid, NULL, [](void* ptr)->void *{
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(10ms);  //  assuming the copy took a while
        auto val_ptr = static_cast<data_to_new_thread_t*>(ptr);
        auto val = val_ptr->val;  // <-- copy from main thread
        pthread_cond_signal(&val_ptr->cv);
        std::cout<<"new pthread: copied"<<std::endl;
        for (int i = 0; i<5; ++i) {
            std::cout<<"new pthread: "<<"i:"<<i<<" val:"<<val<<std::endl;
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(10ms);
        }
        return nullptr;
    }, &data);
    std::cout<<"new pthread created"<<std::endl;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&data.mux);
    pthread_cond_wait(&data.cv, &data.mux);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&data.mux);
    std::cout<<"try to detach"<<std::endl; 
    pthread_detach(pid);  // need to make sure val is copied before detach
    std::cout<<"new pthread detached"<<std::endl;
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&data.mux);
    pthread_cond_destroy(&data.cv);
}

void new_std_thread() {
    std::mutex mux;
    std::condition_variable cv;
    bool is_copy_done = false;  // better yet, use std::atomic_bool to avoid race condition

    int val = 22222;
    auto t = std::thread([&](){
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(10ms); // assuming the copy took a while
        auto new_val = val;
        is_copy_done = true;
        cv.notify_all();
        std::cout<<"new thread: copied"<<std::endl;
        for (int i = 0; i<5; ++i) {
            std::cout<<"new thread: "<<"i:"<<i<<" val:"<<new_val<<std::endl;
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(10ms);
        }
    });
    std::cout<<"new thread created"<<std::endl;

    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mux);
    cv.wait(lock, [&is_copy_done]{return is_copy_done;});
    std::cout<<"try to detach"<<std::endl; 
    t.detach();
    std::cout<<"new thread detached"<<std::endl;
}

void new_std_thread_with_capture() {
    int val = 33333;
    auto t = std::thread([val](){  // MUST capture by value here
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(100ms); // wait a while for detach
        for (int i = 0; i<5; ++i) {
            std::cout<<"new thread with capture: "<<"i:"<<i<<" val:"<<val<<std::endl;
            // will print "val:33333", even if val is changed/destroyed outside
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(10ms);
        }
    });
    val = 11111;  // change to val won't affect the new thread
    std::cout<<"new thread created"<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"try to detach"<<std::endl; 
    t.detach();
    std::cout<<"new thread detached"<<std::endl;
}

int main() {
    new_pthread();
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
    std::cout<<"=================="<<std::endl;
    new_std_thread();
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
    std::cout<<"=================="<<std::endl;
    new_std_thread_with_capture();
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
}
```

Comment: You have a race condition in `new_std_thread` since you do `is_copy_done = true;` in the thread unsynchronized.  In `new_std_thread_with_capture` it's even worse since `val` may very well be destroyed when you read it in the thread. Also, what's up with idea to `detach` the thread? It just complicates this.

Comment: @TedLyngmo could you please explain on the race condition part? Since only the newly created thread would change `is_copy_done` to `true`, I am a bit confused as to how it would create a race condition.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Also, for the `new_std_thread_with_capture`, my understand is that `val` would be copied inside the lambda when the new thread creates. So what happens to `val` outside won't matter anymore.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I am hoping to refactor an thread creation function so that it takes more than `void *(*)(void *)`. Sometimes when this function is called, the newly created thread gets detached immediately, and refactor all those detach would be a much bigger task.

Comment: _"refactor all those detach would be a much bigger task"_ - You could put them in a container instead of detaching though. The race in `new_std_thread` is because you do `is_copy_done = true;` while the main thread may be reading the variable. `new_std_thread_with_capture` doesn't have the issue I though it had. I thought it was taking `val` by reference but I see now that it copies.